# That day or UNTIL that day?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't quite understand the sentence in bold. Can someone explain it to me, pls? Does it mean "But he often keeps some on hand to sell to those who want to drive out in their new Rolls-Royce or Lamborghini while waiting for the car they ordered?"

Customers often order these cars to their exact specifications and wait months for them to be built, Miller said. **But he often keeps some on hand to sell to those who want to drive out in their new Rolls-Royce or Lamborghini that day**. That's just not possible right now, he said. He can't keep the cars on the lot.

Source: https://edition.cnn.com/2021/04/01/success/luxury-car-sales-pandemic-2020/index.html

Comment: No, he keeps some in reserve for people who want to purchase a luxury car the day they see one rather than waiting for a car to be made to their specifications. It's often referred to as impulse buying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interpretation is partly correct.  There are two types of customers.

Super-rich people who go to buy a Rolls-Royce or Lamborgini (luxury cars) will often have a *bespoke* car build for them.  This takes months.  But some people just want to buy a standard car, and they don't want to wait.

So Miller kept some standard cars *in stock*, so a person who doesn't want to wait can buy one for cash and not have to wait.  "That day" refers to the day that they visit the shop. As Ronald says, this is called "impulse buying".

(All this reminds us of how stupidly rich the stupid-rich are)

Comment: Oh to be stupidly rich!